# How expensive is using a System.Action?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am in a situation where I rely on a `System.Action` to clean up my UI when a method finishes running. Because this method can be called from different points in the application the cleanup actions may be vastly different.

I'm worried they may be expensive, and that I should find another way to handle the situation.

```
MoveObject(myControl, new Thickness(0, 1, 2, 3), a =>
                        {
                            myButton.IsEnabled = true;
                            myGrid.IsEnabled = true;
                            myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
                        });

private void MoveObject(FrameworkElement control, Thickness margins, Action<wMain> action, double speedCoefficient = 1)
    {
        var speed = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt64(_defaultAnimationSpeed.Ticks*speedCoefficient));
        var animation = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            From = control.Margin,
            To = margins,
            Duration = speed
        };
        var finalAction = new Action<wMain>(a =>
        {
            action(this);
            control.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, null); //Clear the animation so the property can be set manually.
            control.Margin = margins;
        });
        animation.Completed += (sender, args) => { Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(finalAction, this); };
        control.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, animation);
    }
```

I sometimes also execute actions by writing `action(this);` instead of calling the Dispatcher.  Is one better than the other?

Comment: Have you profiled your application and actually measured the expense of using `System.Action`? That would be far more reliable than us guessing.

Comment: There is no interaction with the UI that isn't "expensive". One more delegate won't change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate invocations are rather cheap; don't worry about it.

You only need the dispatcher if you aren't on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks.  I am doing quite a bit on background threads, so I do use the Dispatcher frequently.

Comment: @DunningKrugerEffect: Consider using `await Task.Run()` instead of background threads.

Comment: I'm using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` in place of Tasks when I want something to run and don't care when it finishes.  I may be able to use `await Task.Run()` in place of my actions, though.

Comment: @DunningKrugerEffect: If you ever find yourself going back to the UI thread (`Dispatcher`) from the threadpool, replace it with `await Task.Run()`.